# Compare each row to the other rows in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a column of values (X).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [2,3,5,2]})
```

For each row, I would like to find the average of the X values from the other rows (A).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anky. How could I use that to get the column A? I don't want to include the row that I am on!

Comment: sorry  didnt understand the question, can you explain a bit more. THe logic

Comment: What is your expected output.

Comment: It's what I've put in the column A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mean of the other rows is the sum of the column minus the row value divided by the size of the column minus 1. In Pandas it writes:

```
df['A'] = (df['X'].sum() - df['X'])/(len(df) - 1)
```

Comment: pandas is amazing :D